# XPS печать, синхронная и асинхронная

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Ситуация следующая:
Есть код:

```
        Visual printcanvas = createViz();
        var xpsDockWrtr = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printDialog.PrintQueue); 
        xpsDockWrtr.WriteAsync(printcanvas);
```

Если вызвать его в цикле скажем раз 10 то по факту до очереди печати дойдёт 7-9 заданий. Если 20 то 3-4. Если больше 50 то вообще ничего не напечатает.

В то же время если заменить строчку `xpsDockWrtr.WriteAsync(printcanvas);` на `xpsDockWrtr.Write(printcanvas);` то отпечатает столько, сколько раз вызвал метод.

Поясните, почему при асинхронной печати часть, а то и все задания печати "пропадают"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В то же время если заменить строчку xpsDockWrtr.WriteAsync(printcanvas); на xpsDockWrtr.Write(printcanvas); то отпечатает столько, сколько раз вызвал метод.

конечно, т.к. `xpsDockWrtr.Write` не возвращает управление до тех, пор пока не выполнится метод.

Такой вариант сразу же возвращает управление в вызывающий метод:

```
xpsDockWrtr.WriteAsync(printcanvas);
```

И если такое действие крутится в цикле, то какой результат следует ожидать когда печать не завершилась, а метод вызван повторно?

Думаю правильней будет использовать так:

```
await xpsDockWrtr.WriteAsync(printcanvas);
```

`await` заставит дождаться окончания печати и в итоге отпечатается столько, сколько раз был вызван этот метод в цикле. При этом интерфейс не будет заблокирован на время печати.